# Cannot return two different types in Python

Tags: python-3.x

my code is attached below. I cannot seem to return two different results from different classes. When I return the result from either of the two classes individually, it works. How can I make it return both of them at a single result? I tried commas, it didn't work.

`The tiger weighs 310kg, has a lifespan of 26 years and can run at a maximum speed of 65kph. It also has a striped coat.`

The error always shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(tiger)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

Code:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, mass, lifespan, speed):
        self.mass_in_kg = mass
        self.lifespan_in_years = lifespan
        self.speed_in_kph = speed

    def vocalize(self):
        print("Chuff")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The {type(self).__name__.lower()} "\
            f"weighs {self.mass_in_kg}kg,"\
            f" has a lifespan of {self.lifespan_in_years} years and "\
            f"can run at a maximum speed of {self.speed_in_kph}kph."


# Write your Tiger class here
class Tiger(Cat):
    def __init__(self, mass, lifespan, speed):
        super().__init__(mass, lifespan, speed)
        self.coat_pattern = "striped"

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__(), {self.coat_pattern}



# This code is used to test your class
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tiger = Tiger(310, 26, 65)
    print(tiger)
```

Comment: You could use something like `return " ".join((super().__str__()[:-1], self.coat_pattern))` or even `super().__str__()[:-1] + " " + self.coat_pattern` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a single string. This can be done in multiple ways, for example:

```py
class Tiger(Cat):
    def __init__(self, mass, lifespan, speed):
        super().__init__(mass, lifespan, speed)
        self.coat_pattern = "striped"

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} My coat pattern is {}.".format(super().__str__(), self.coat_pattern)
```

or the way you do in `Cat`:

```py
class Tiger(Cat):
    def __init__(self, mass, lifespan, speed):
        super().__init__(mass, lifespan, speed)
        self.coat_pattern = "striped"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{super().__str__()} My coat pattern is {self.coat_pattern}."
```

would probably be best. Basically you just want to call `super().__str__()` and *concatenate* the returned string with whatever string you want to have in addition when calling `Tiger.__str__` and return the concatenated string.